# Get password from android account

Tags: android, email, passwords

I noticed from Android API, they have this method `getPassword(Account account)`.

```
accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

Account[] allGoogleAccounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

for (Account account : allGoogleAccounts) 

{
  System.out.println(accountManager.getPassword(account));
}
```

But I have this error:

```
11-16 10:49:08.986: WARN/System.err(5732): java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10039 is different than the authenticator's uid
11-16 10:49:09.038: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
11-16 10:49:09.038: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
11-16 10:49:09.045: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getPassword(IAccountManager.java:415)
11-16 10:49:09.087: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.getPassword(AccountManager.java:277)
11-16 10:49:09.087: WARN/System.err(5732):     at com.test.account.onCreate(account.java:30)
11-16 10:49:09.107: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-16 10:49:09.107: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-16 10:49:09.125: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-16 10:49:09.125: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-16 10:49:09.134: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-16 10:49:09.156: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 10:49:09.156: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-16 10:49:09.166: WARN/System.err(5732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-16 10:49:09.175: WARN/System.err(5732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 10:49:09.185: WARN/System.err(5732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-16 10:49:09.185: WARN/System.err(5732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-16 10:49:09.195: WARN/System.err(5732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-16 10:49:09.206: WARN/System.err(5732):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone can tell me my mistake?

Comment: any luck for you for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

From [AccountManager.getPassword()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts]/AccountManager.html#getPassword(android.accounts.Account))

> `getPassword`: 
>   This method requires the caller to hold the permission `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` and to have the same `UID` as the account's authenticator.

The way I see it you can only get the password if your app was the app that created the account in account manager (Could be mistaking though)

Answer (score 1):

in account manager if you(your app) write the account then only you(your app) can get the password this is because of security that on app could get the password of the user that he used to sync in other app

you can get the password of the account the is created by your process **UID** every process have it own **UID** once it runs on the device and continue to have the same **UID** ever